# NUnit Test framework for ASP MVC 4

Tags: nunit, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I create nunit testing project in asp.net mvc 4? I have followed the steps in the below link

http://www.geoffhudik.com/tech/2012/4/21/aspnet-mvc-4-nunit-template.html

But, I can't find the NUnit test option when creating MVC 4 application. But this option will be shown for MVC 3 application.

Please anyone let me know the solution for MVC 4.

Answer (score 0):

Things are much simpler now:

1. Inside VS2012, go to Tools - Extensions and Updates - Online -
   Visual Studio Gallery.
2. Search for **NUnit**.
3. Select **ASP.NET MVC NUnit**.
4. Click **Download**.
5. When it has downloaded, you will need to restart Visual Studio.

Voila, you have everything you were after from this page.

(I'm not sure, but I think this only works for Standard Edition and higher. Please correct me, if this works for Express Edition.)